# AWS Mysterious Drives

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an Windows Server 2008 AWS instance. I stopped the instance and started it back up and my D:\ EBS volume is now missing. In its place, I have two mysterious drives I cannot account for.

[image]

Inspecting the instance details, I show only one attached device (the C:) drive.

Any what these additional drives are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each AWS instance comes with its own storage. For example, a M1 Large has 2x420 GB storage devices. It looks like that may be what you have.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html

Comment: It's important to note the disclaimer on the linked page: *"do not rely on instance store for valuable, long-term data."*  These volumes are ephemeral.  Also, most, but not all, instance classes include these volumes.  The t2 classes, for example, do not include them.